# Can't click button with selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

I'm a newcomer when it comes to javascript and selenium. I have created a simple add to cart project, but the one i am currently working on im having some troubles. The HTML code is:

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
<button type="button" class="dark" onclick="shippingMethod.save()" onkeypress="shippingMethod.save()">Continue</button>
<span id="shipping-method-please-wait" class="please-wait icon icon--notch" style="display:none;">
Loading next step... </span>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out anyway where i can click the Continue button. I have tried things such as

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Continue")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button)).click();
```

and many other combinations but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the element by its class name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("dark").click();
```

Comment: I've just tried this method as well, and it still does not respond. There are multiple classes that are named "dark" in the HTML code, I'm not sure if that plays a part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have used implicit wait. If not we need to add it.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Also try this below xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Continue']")).click();
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code using `cssSelector` locator.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='dark'][type='button']")).click();
```

> OR

Try to click the button using `java-script` executor.

```
WebElement continue_button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='dark'][type='button']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", continue_button);
```